# Custom user in django raises ValueError

Tags: python, django, django-1.7, django-custom-user

Even this simple example throws a `ValueError: Dependency on app with no migrations: myApp` during `python manage.py syncdb`

**myApp/models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myApp.User'
```

---

Running `./manage syncdb` in django==1.6.5 **<< works**

```
Creating tables ...
```

Running `./manage syncdb` in django==1.7 **<< breaks**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/web_development/tutorials/python_social_auth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/web_development/tutorials/python_social_auth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/web_development/tutorials/python_social_auth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/web_development/tutorials/python_social_auth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/web_development/tutorials/python_social_auth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 533, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/web_development/tutorials/python_social_auth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 27, in handle_noargs
    call_command("migrate", **options)
  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/web_development/tutorials/python_social_auth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 115, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/web_development/tutorials/python_social_auth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/web_development/tutorials/python_social_auth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 63, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/web_development/tutorials/python_social_auth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/web_development/tutorials/python_social_auth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/web_development/tutorials/python_social_auth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 239, in build_graph
    parent = self.check_key(parent, key[0])
  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/web_development/tutorials/python_social_auth/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 163, in check_key
    raise ValueError("Dependency on app with no migrations: %s" % key[0])
ValueError: Dependency on app with no migrations: myApp
```

I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation for 1.7 that says this should be done any differently that 1.6. It does look like some other people have had [this problem too](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23366), but as a result from running `./manage.py migrate --list`

Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: If you just wanna create a new database and you don't care about  data migration, you may also delete `myApp/migration` directory. In my case `migrate` started to work only after it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I guess I was looking in the wrong place for an answer:

I solved this by running: `./manage.py makemigrations myApp`

```
(env)Bens-MacBook-Pro:social_auth bdhammel$ ./manage.py makemigrations myApp
Migrations for 'myApp':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model User
(env)Bens-MacBook-Pro:social_auth bdhammel$ python manage.py syncdb
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: sessions, admin, myApp, auth, default, contenttypes
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying auth.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying app.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying admin.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying default.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... FAKED

You have installed Django's auth system, and don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
```

via https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#s-custom-fields

**EDIT**
I should have used `python manage.py migrate` instead of `python manage.py syncdb`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.7/#schema-migrations

> syncdb has been deprecated and replaced by migrate. Don’t worry - calls to syncdb will still work as before.

Answer (score 5):

1. Delete migrations folder in each app
2. Drop table django_migrations
3. Run `python3 manage.py makemigrations app1`
4. Run `python3 manage.py makemigrations app2`

---

`manage.py runserver` should now work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I moved an app into a clean new project without deleting the migrations. If you don't care about the migrations and are starting a project from scratch, consider removing the migrations from those apps.